# Two-stage least squares approach to Deming regression

Tags: least-squares, instrumental-variables, 2sls, total-least-squares

I am interested in statistical inference for the Deming regression model: 
$$ x_i=x^*_i + \epsilon_i$$
$$ y_i = (\alpha+\beta x^*_i) + \epsilon'_i$$
where the $x^*_i$'s are nonrandom fixed numbers, $\epsilon_i \sim {\cal N}(0,\sigma_x^2)$, $\epsilon'_i \sim {\cal N}(0,\sigma_y^2)$, and all variables $\epsilon_i, \epsilon'_i$ are mutually independent. I particularly focus on the case of the assumption $\sigma_x=\sigma_y$.

[Graham Dunn's slides](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Graham.Dunn/MSc%20Biostatistics/Linear%20Regression%20with%20errors.pdf) show how to treat the Deming regression with a two-stage least squares approach when the $x^*_i$'s are random (this model is sometimes termed as the ultrastructural model in the literature). I would like to know how to similarly treat the case when the $x^*_i$'s are nonrandom and whether it is possible to perform this approach with [John Fox's "sem" R package.](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/sem/html/tsls.html)